# Pass an object to a function in jint and return a value

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, jint

I'm attempting to pass an object to a javascript function via [jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) and return a value. But it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have tried so far -

Error -

```
Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException: 'obj is undefined'
```

Using the following code -

```
var carObj = JsonSerializer.Serialize(car);  

var engine = new Jint.Engine();
engine.SetValue("obj", carObj);

var value = engine
           .Execute("const result = (function car(obj) { const type = obj.Type; return type;})()")
           .GetValue("result");
```

Comment: I am not familiar with jint, but I'd **guess** that `function car(obj)` creates a local `obj` that hides your "global" `obj`. And that local `obj` would be indeed undefined. First thing I'd try would be to just do `function car() { ... // same code from here`.

Comment: @Fildor I tried a simple function without any parameter and it seems to work - 
`function car() { const myTemplate = 3 + 5;`
Only I need to know to pass an object

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? I believe `obj` should be available globally in the script.

Comment: I tried, there is no error, but result is `undefined`.

Comment: Ok, then my assumption seems to be incorrect, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint#examples), you should pass your POCO `car` directly to [`Jint.Engine`](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint/blob/master/Jint/Engine.cs) rather than trying to serialize it to JSON. Jint will use reflection to access its members.

Thus your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
var value = new Jint.Engine()  // Create the Jint engine
    .Execute("function car(obj) { const type = obj.Type; return type;}") // Define a function car() that accesses the Type field of the incoming obj and returns it.
    .Invoke("car", car);  // Invoke the car() function on the car POCO, and return its result.
```

Or equivalently as:

```
var value = new Jint.Engine()
    .SetValue("obj", car) // Define a "global" variable "obj"
    .Execute("const result = (function car(obj) { const type = obj.Type; return type;})(obj)") // Define the car() function, call it with "obj", and set the value in "result"
    .GetValue("result"); // Get the evaluated value of "result"
```

Or

```
var value = new Jint.Engine()  // Create the Jint engine
    .SetValue("obj", car) // Define a "global" variable "obj"
    .Execute("function car(obj) { const type = obj.Type; return type;}; car(obj);") // Define the car() function, and call it with "obj".
    .GetCompletionValue();  // Get the last evaluated statement completion value
```

Here I am assuming that `car` is a POCO that has a string property `Type`, e.g.

```
var car = new 
{
    Type = "studebaker convertible",
};
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7IeQcx).